# Selecting only a href tags within a div and disable them

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to figure out how to disable links within a specific div.  What I currently have is this...

```
    function Lock() {
    var obj = document.getElementById("tempplateInfo");
    obj.disabled = 'true';
    $(function () {
        //grab all a tags
        $('a').each(function () {
            //click on a link....
            $(this).click(function () {
                alert($(this).attr('href') + ' is not available');
                //disable link
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This currently select all the link on the page.  I don't want all the links, just the few that are inside of a div?

Anyway to get that done... I thought about 'divId a'.  But that didn't work at all, all the links were suddenly available.  I am doing this using jquery btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to learn [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

You want `#someId a`.

Comment: ah, I forgot my pound sign char.  I need to get better at jquery.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#divId a').each(function () {
```

This will select all `a` within the element with ID 'divId'.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("#myId a").attr("href","javascript:void();");
});
```